# What are the time gaps in my Debug Log?

Tags: debugging

Trying to work out why a data load is taking so long...when I look in the logs, I see a couple of places where there seems to be a long gap between one thing ending, and the next starting e.g.

```
16:49:26.0 (28050140)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|ContactTrigger on Contact trigger event BeforeUpdate for [200 Contact Ids]
16:49:34.651 (8651985516)|CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[13]|01pU0000000sLvJ|<init>()
16:49:34.651 (8652007058)|CONSTRUCTOR_EXIT|[13]|01pU0000000sLvJ|<init>()
16:49:34.651 (8653493286)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|ContactTrigger on Contact trigger event AfterUpdate for [200 Ids]
```

Is the log misleading, so that the first line doesn't really finish until 16:49:34.651, or is there something else going on? The 01pU0000000sLvJ is the id of the trigger handler class that is invoked...

Answer (score 2):

You can put the log level to finest and trace the log. Maybe some other updates (triggers, workflow flow field updates etc. may be occurring)

Answer (score 0):

I think what I have worked out is this...the Contact trigger was setup to fire on before update and after update, but the code in the trigger only did anything for before update (the after update piece was commented out)

Once I removed the redundant event, the gap seemed to go away...